# Is there a way to call the "Select By Location" dialog box and gain access to the parameters

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3

In an application that I am developing using VB.Net with ArcObjects 9.3, I am trying to display the "Select By Location" dialog box in my code.  I know that I can call it directly using the UID through the ICommandItem interface, but I also need access to the parameters set by the dialog box (e.g. the selection layer, the selection method, and so on-- something that I don't think is possible with the UID method) .  Is there a  way to do this somehow that I'm missing, similar to the way that you can call the "Select By Attribute" dialog box using the IQueryAttributes interface?

Comment: I think the short answer is no. Application dialogs don't seem to offer a hook into their interfaces.

Comment: The Select By Attribute tool has a hook into it, via the IQueryAttribute interface.  The third comment on this forum has some example code:  http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=291805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used that interface so a good find indeed! But I'm still not convinced the dialog is exposed...

An alternative is to open up and display the selectbylocation geo-processing tool? The following VBA code opens the Calculate Field tool but it gives the basic syntax for populating parameters and opening up the interface.

```vb
Public Sub OpenCalculateTool()
    ' Hook into Toolbox and get the tool
    Dim pUID As New UID
    pUID = "esriGeoprocessingUI.ArcToolboxExtension"
    Dim pArcToolboxExtension As IArcToolboxExtension
    Set pArcToolboxExtension = Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(pUID)
    Dim pArcToolbox As IArcToolbox
    Set pArcToolbox = pArcToolboxExtension.ArcToolbox
    Dim pGPTool As IGPTool
    Set pGPTool = pArcToolbox.GetToolbyNameString("CalculateField")

    ' Create messages, required by Invoke method
    Dim msgs As IGPMessages
    Set msgs = New GPMessages

    ' Get existing parameter structure
    Dim pArray As IArray
    Set pArray = pGPTool.ParameterInfo

    ' Declare Parameter interfaces
    Dim pGPParameter As IGPParameter
    Dim pGPDataType As IGPDataType
    Dim pGPParameterEdit As IGPParameterEdit

    ' Set the parameters of the tool
    Set pGPParameter = pArray.Element(0)
    Set pGPParameterEdit = pGPParameter
    Set pGPDataType = pGPParameter.DataType
    Set pGPParameterEdit.Value = pGPDataType.CreateValue("a") ' Featurelayer name
    Set pGPParameter = pArray.Element(1)
    Set pGPParameterEdit = pGPParameter
    Set pGPDataType = pGPParameter.DataType
    Set pGPParameterEdit.Value = pGPDataType.CreateValue("xx") ' Field
    Set pGPParameter = pArray.Element(3)
    Set pGPParameterEdit = pGPParameter
    Set pGPDataType = pGPParameter.DataType
    Set pGPParameterEdit.Value = pGPDataType.CreateValue("VB")

    ' Open the tool
    Dim pGPToolCommandHelper As IGPToolCommandHelper2
    Set pGPToolCommandHelper = New GPToolCommandHelper
    pGPToolCommandHelper.SetTool pGPTool
    pGPToolCommandHelper.InvokeModal 0, pArray, True, msgs
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome!  This looks like it might do the job!  Thanks so much!!